# Starting Kopete to system tray

Tags: kde, kubuntu, notification-area, kopete

Does anyone know how I can start Kopete minimized to the system tray? I'm using KDE 4.5.1 on Kubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the default changed in 10.10 (even upgrading from 10.4) - just go into Kopete's Settings -> Configure -> Behavior and check the box. You might have to restart Kopete.

Comment: Unfortunately its not present. Everytime i login to KDE my kopete window pops up.